# Resize Flat Button and give Horizontal Scrolling option in flutter

Tags: listview, button, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, flutter

[image]

If you can see at the top , I have created 4 columns with an Flat button containing an image and a text . I want to give exact width and height for the Flat button is that possible ? Also , I want to give a horizontal scroll so that I can add more columns in the same row. Also , onclick of an image , the corresponding list should be shown below . Here is my code uptil now.

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'widgets.dart';

    void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Booze Up',
      theme: new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.red,
),
home: new MyHomePage('Booze Up'),
routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
  "/MyHomePage2": (BuildContext context) => new MyHome()
}
));

       class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

    int counter =0;
    String title;
    MyHomePage(this.title);

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {


        Text text = new Text("dev");
       Text text2 = new Text("Sneha");
       Text text3 = new Text("Prashant");

var pad = const EdgeInsets.all(10.0);

Padding pad1 = new Padding(child: text, padding:pad);
 Padding pad2 = new Padding(child: text2, padding:pad);
  Padding pad3 = new Padding(child: text3, padding:pad);

     ListView listView = new ListView(children: <Widget>[new 
     Image.asset('images/party.jpg'),pad1,pad2,pad3]);

  Drawer drawer = new Drawer(child:listView); 

// This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
// by the _incrementCounter method above.
//
// The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
// fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
// than having to individually change instances of widgets.
return new Scaffold(
  drawer: drawer,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: new Text(title),
  ),
  body:
  new Center(

    // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
    // in the middle of the parent.
    child: new Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.camera),
              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0,0.0, 5.0,0.0)),
            new RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.black,
          child: 
          new Text(  'Party Home',
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontStyle: 
               FontStyle.italic,color: Colors.white),
                   ),
          onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/MyHomePage2");
          },                
       )]),
       new Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: <Widget>[
         new Icon(Icons.favorite),
        new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0,0.0, 5.0,0.0)),
        new Text(
          'Pub Hopping',
         style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),

        ),
         ]),
        new Image.asset('images/party.jpg'),   
          ],
        )
        , 
    ),

  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: null,
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
   }


  }

        class MyHome extends StatefulWidget
        {
         @override
        State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyHomePage2();
         }

        class MyHomePage2 extends State<MyHome> {
        List items = new List() ;


        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {

var abc = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

print(abc.width);

var width = abc.width/4;

         Text text = new Text("Dev");
        Text text2 = new Text("Sneha");
        Text text3 = new Text("Prashant");
      Text text4 = new Text("Vikesh");

var pad = const EdgeInsets.all(10.0);

Padding pad1 = new Padding(child: text, padding:pad);
 Padding pad2 = new Padding(child: text2, padding:pad);
  Padding pad3 = new Padding(child: text3, padding:pad);
  Padding pad4 = new Padding(child: text4, padding:pad);

      ListView listView = new ListView(children: <Widget>[new 
      Image.asset('images/party.jpg'),pad1,pad2,pad3,pad4]);


     ListView listView2 = new ListView(children: <Widget>[new Text("Jacob 
        Creek"),new Text("Sula red"),new Text("Yellow tale"),new 
        Text("Chenin Blanc")]);

        Drawer drawer = new Drawer(child: listView);

return new Scaffold(
  drawer: drawer,

  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Booze Up'),
  ),
  body:
     new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
           children: <Widget>[
                 new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(child: new 
         Image.asset('images/party.jpg',width:width,height: 
          width),onPressed: buildlist('button1'),),
          new Text('Juice', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontStyle: 
          FontStyle.italic)),        
          ]),
                new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(child: new 
       Image.asset('images/party.jpg',width:width,height: width),onPressed: 
        buildlist('button2')),
          new Text('Cocktail', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 
         20.0,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)) ,                     
          ]),
                  new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(child: new Image.asset('images/party.jpg',width:width,height: width),onPressed: buildlist('button3')),
          new Text('Moocktail', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
          ]),
                  new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
     new FlatButton(child: new Image.asset('images/party.jpg',width:width,height: width),onPressed: buildlist('button4')),
          new Text('Juice', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
          ])
           ]),
        new Expanded(
          child: new ListView(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 0.0,10.0),
            children: items,
          ),
        )]
     ),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: null,
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
            }

buildlist(String s ) {

    print("entered buildlist"+ s);

  List refresh = new List();
  if(s=='button1')
  {
  refresh = [
   new Refreshments("Watermelon",250),
    new Refreshments("Orange",275),
    new Refreshments("Pine",300),
    new Refreshments("Papaya",225),
     new Refreshments("Apple",250),
];
  }
  else if(s=='button2')

    { refresh = [
      new Refreshments("Pina Colada",250),
      new Refreshments("Bloody Mary",275),
      new Refreshments("Long Island Ice tea",300),
      new Refreshments("Screwdriver",225),
      new Refreshments("Fusion Cocktail",250),
];
    }
    else if(s=='button3')
    {
    refresh  = [
       new Refreshments("Virgin Pina Colada",250),
      new Refreshments("Virgin Mary",275),
       new Refreshments("Strawberry Flush",300),
      new Refreshments("Mango Diver",225),
      new Refreshments("Peach Delight",250),
];
    }
    else{
 refresh = [
       new Refreshments("Absolute",250),
       new Refreshments("Smirnoff",275),
        new Refreshments("White Mischief",300),
        new Refreshments("Romanov",225),
        new Refreshments("Blender's Pride",250),
];
    }


 for(var item in refresh)
 {
   items.add(new ItemsList(item));
 }

  }


                 }

       class  Refreshments 
 {
        String name;
          int price;

           Refreshments(this.name,this.price);
 }


            class ItemsList extends StatelessWidget
      {
            final Refreshments refreshments;

           ItemsList (this.refreshments);

      @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new ListTile(
      onTap: null,
      title: new Text(refreshments.name),
  );

         }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. To have an exact `width` and `height`, use a `Container` as the parent to your `FlatButton`, it provides you with these properties.
   *[Darky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/darky) pointed out that using [`SizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) is a better solution.
2. Use a `ListView` and specify that `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to enable horizontal scrolling.
3. Using `ListView.builder` gives you the ability to loop through your list of children widgets, such that you can now the widget that is being interacted with by simply reading the index of a widget in the list.

**Example**

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class LetsParty extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LetsPartyState createState() => new _LetsPartyState();
}

class _LetsPartyState extends State<LetsParty> {
  Image _partyImage = new Image.network(
      "http://www.freshcardsgifts.co.uk/images/_lib/animal-party-greetings-card-3003237-0-1344698261000.jpg");
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Let's Party"),),
      body: new ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 10, //add the length of your list here
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[

                ///Flexible let's your widget flex in  the given space, dealing with the overflow you have
                //  new Flexible(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: ()=>print("You pressed Image No.$index"), child: _partyImage)),
                new Container(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: () =>
                    scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                        content: new Text("You pressed Image No.$index"))),
                    child: _partyImage),
                  width: 100.0, height: 100.0,),
                //Exact width and height, consider adding Flexible as a parent to the Container
                new Text("Text$index")
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `SizedBox` instead of `Container` to resize children. This is clearer and has more options.

Comment: This is a very good demo given by you. It removes a lot of my redundant code . But,  the setState method in buildlist is called even before the page is built , why is that ? In this question , I forgot setState() later I incorporated it in my program . Please can u help.

Comment: @DivyangShah I am sorry I do not see any setState in your code

Comment: that's what i included it later , after posting this question . The main issue is buildlist()  is called even before the page has loaded. I have enclosed the code in buildlist inside setState .Like buildlist() { setState( () { ...code});}

Comment: This is irrelevant to what are you were asking here, maybe open another question with the relevant code.

Comment: Link for the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build