# setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

Tags: listview, dart, size, flutter, setstate

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyHomePage2();
}

class MyHomePage2 extends State<MyHome> {
  List items = new List();

  buildlist(String s) {
    setState(() {
      print("entered buildlist" + s);
      List refresh = new List();
      if (s == 'button0') {
        refresh = [
          new Refreshments("Watermelon", 250),
          new Refreshments("Orange", 275),
          new Refreshments("Pine", 300),
          new Refreshments("Papaya", 225),
          new Refreshments("Apple", 250),
        ];
      } else if (s == 'button1') {
        refresh = [
          new Refreshments("Pina Colada", 250),
          new Refreshments("Bloody Mary", 275),
          new Refreshments("Long Island Ice tea", 300),
          new Refreshments("Screwdriver", 225),
          new Refreshments("Fusion Cocktail", 250),
        ];
      } else if (s == 'button2') {
        refresh = [
          new Refreshments("Virgin Pina Colada", 250),
          new Refreshments("Virgin Mary", 275),
          new Refreshments("Strawberry Flush", 300),
          new Refreshments("Mango Diver", 225),
          new Refreshments("Peach Delight", 250),
        ];
      } else {
        refresh = [
          new Refreshments("Absolute", 250),
          new Refreshments("Smirnoff", 275),
          new Refreshments("White Mischief", 300),
          new Refreshments("Romanov", 225),
          new Refreshments("Blender's Pride", 250),
        ];
      }

      for (var item in refresh) {
        items.add(new ItemsList(item));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var abc = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    print(abc.width);

    var width = abc.width / 4;

    Text text = new Text("Dev");
    Text text2 = new Text("Sneha");
    Text text3 = new Text("Prashant");
    Text text4 = new Text("Vikesh");

    var pad = const EdgeInsets.all(10.0);

    Padding pad1 = new Padding(child: text, padding: pad);
    Padding pad2 = new Padding(child: text2, padding: pad);
    Padding pad3 = new Padding(child: text3, padding: pad);
    Padding pad4 = new Padding(child: text4, padding: pad);

    ListView listView = new ListView(children: <Widget>[
      new Image.asset('images/party.jpg'),
      pad1,
      pad2,
      pad3,
      pad4
    ]);

    Drawer drawer = new Drawer(child: listView);

    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: drawer,

      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Booze Up'),
      ),
      body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Column(children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                child: new Flexible(
                    child: new FlatButton(
                  child: new Image.asset('images/party.jpg',
                      width: width, height: width),
                  onPressed: buildlist('button' + index.toString()),
                )),
                width: width,
                height: width,
              )
            ]);
          },
        ),
        new Expanded(
            child: new ListView(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
          children: items,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        )),
      ]),

      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class Refreshments {
  String name;
  int price;

  Refreshments(this.name, this.price);
}

class ItemsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final Refreshments refreshments;

  ItemsList(this.refreshments);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(
      onTap: null,
      title: new Text(refreshments.name),
    );
  }
}
```

[Full code](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/45ebdf271cf45e20a7ad5f5564742517)

I am having two errors:

1] Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height .
A horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.

2] setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build
A vertical renderflex overflowed by 99488 pixels.

Please help me with it . I am creating this app where on each image click a list should be shown below . The images will be in a row and the list should be shown below the row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 602):

In my case I was calling the `setState` method before the `build` method had completed the process of building the widgets.

You can face this error if you are showing a `snackBar` or an `alertDialog` before the completion of the `build` method, as well as in many other cases. So, in such cases you should use a callback function as shown below:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){

  // Add Your Code here.

});
```

or you can also use `SchedulerBinding` which does the same:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

  // add your code here.

  Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NextPage()));
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This error occurred to me when I was creating a new `MaterialPageRoute` in a `FutureBuilder` (a login success screen).

Comment: This is working, thanks! I was getting the same issue when calling `Navigator.of(context).popUntil` method

Comment: I used it to display SfCalendar half screen on month view and full screen on schedule view. Worked seamlessly. Thanks!

Comment: This work for me SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback

Answer (score 206):

Your code

```
onPressed: buildlist('button'+index.toString()),
```

executes `buildlist()` and passes the result to `onPressed`, but that is not the desired behavior.

It should be

```
onPressed: () => buildlist('button'+index.toString()),
```

This way a function (closure) is passed to `onPressed`, that when executed, calls `buildlist()`

Comment: I am still getting the error: Horizontal viewport  was given unbounded height . What does that mean ?

Comment: I guess I have to leave that one to @Darky or someone else.

Comment: @DivyangShah you are using a Container as the parent of Flexible, it should be the other way around.

Comment: resolve my error, does't understand this difference . maybe there's link to more detail about that?

Comment: @chengxcv5 look up "closures". The difference is that if you assign a reference to a function to `onPressed`, that function can be called by the widget when it recognizes a tap. The problem with the code in the question is, that it doesn't pass a function, instead the function is called immediately and the return value of that function is assigned to `onPressed`. The `() => ...` makes it an inline function without a name (closure) and here without parameters, that when called executes `buildlist(...)`

Comment: Important distinction here is - passing the function itself versus it's return value. thank you..this worked for me. Also here's a link explaining what a function "Closure" is - Function defined inside another function (parent) often have unrestricted access to the local variables of the parent function. Some languages allow this and Dart is one of them. https://medium.com/flutter-community/understanding-lexical-closures-in-dart-flutter-863ec361a614

Answer (score 133):

I was also setting the state during build, so, I deferred it to the next tick and it worked.

**previously**

```dart
myFunction()
```

**New**

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
  myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me..
In my case I'm doing Infinite gridview and I was trying to show loading view at bottom and onBuild called to many times.. But working with this solution, Thanks again..

Comment: this works also: Future(() async { myFunction(); });

Comment: worked for me. Had to use it with a ChangeNotifierProvider( )

Comment: This is a bad idea. It's a workaround that will not work 100% of the time.

Comment: @Fred could you enlighten us as to what case will it not work?

Comment: It solves a problem but creates a race condition

Comment: @Fred what race condition?

Answer (score 26):

The problem with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` is that, it isn't an all encompassing solution.

As per the contract of [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) -

> Schedule a callback for the end of this frame.
> [...]
> This callback is run during a frame, just after the persistent frame
> callbacks [...]. If a frame is in progress and post-frame callbacks haven't
> been executed yet, then the registered callback is still executed
> during the frame. **Otherwise, the registered callback is executed
> during the next frame.**

That last line sounds like a deal-breaker to me.

This method isn't equipped to handle the case where there is no "current frame", and the flutter engine is idle. Of course, in that case, one can invoke `setState()` directly, but again, that won't *always* work - sometimes there just *is* a current frame.

---

Thankfully, in `SchedulerBinding`, there also exists a solution to this little wart - [SchedulerPhase](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerPhase-class.html)

Let's build a better `setState`, one that doesn't complain.

(`endOfFrame` does basically the same thing as `addPostFrameCallback`, except it tries to schedule a new frame at `SchedulerPhase.idle`, and it uses async-await instead of callbacks)

```
Future<bool> rebuild() async {
  if (!mounted) return false;

  // if there's a current frame,
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase != SchedulerPhase.idle) {
    // wait for the end of that frame.
    await SchedulerBinding.instance.endOfFrame;
    if (!mounted) return false;
  }

  setState(() {});
  return true;
}
```

---

This also makes for nicer control flows, that frankly, *just work*.

```
await someTask();

if (!await rebuild()) return;

await someOtherTask();
```

Answer (score 12):

I recieved this error due to a pretty dumb mistake, but maybe someone is here because he did the exact same thing...

In my code i have two classes. One class (B) is just there to create me a special widget with a onTap function. The function that should get triggered by the user tap was in the other class (A). So i was trying to pass the function of class A to the constructor of class B, so that i could assign it to the onTap.

Unfortunatly, instead of passing the functions i called them.
This is what it looked like:

```
ClassB classBInstance = ClassB(...,myFunction());
```

Obviously, this is the correct way:

```
ClassB classBInstance = classB(...,myFunction);
```

This solved my error message.
The error makes sense, because in order for myFunction to work the instance of class B and so my build had to finish first (I am showing a snackbar when calling my function).

Hope this helps someone one day!

Comment: :) haahaha for the first line

Comment: haha thanks so much, that was exactly it:D

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize I had done this mistake... was searching a solution all day long

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the curly bracket `{}` from onTap() in case of InkWell and onPressed() in case of GestureDetector or buttons etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :**
I have faced this issue while navigate to another page using bloc state as below

```
if(state is LoginBtnClickState) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Homepage()));
}
```

Error occurred when doing something before the page build is finished.

**Solution :** in such cases you should use a callback function

```
if(state is LoginBtnClickState) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Homepage()));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to use `addPostFrameCallback` in ChangeNotifierProvider to solve the `setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build` error.

```
//change model state
...
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
  notifyListeners();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you have use **onWillpop** method for going back then come this type of error

```
onWillPop: onBackPressedWillPopeback());
```

replace with this

```
onWillPop: () => onBackPressedWillPopeback());
```

I am sure your error will be solved... If any other query ask me any time...

Comment: This answer was already given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592505/5468463

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to just willy-nilly add a post-frame callback to call call `setState`, like the top answer suggests.

The reason is that if `build` is not currently running, *then there may be no post-frame callback until the user physically interacts with the app, causing another frame to be drawn*. This could mean that `setState` doesn't get called for an arbitrarily long period of time.

This happens when the last frame of animation has already been displayed, and `build` is not currently running. (For example, you could trigger this combination of conditions from a `Timer`.)

Additionally, if your `setState` could be called from anywhere (including from a `Timer`), then you need to check if the widget is `mounted` before calling `setState`, or you could trigger an error saying that the widget is not mounted.

The solution is to add the following `State` extension to your project as `safe_update_state.dart`, then call `safeSetState` where you would normally call `setState`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

extension SafeUpdateState on State {
  void safeSetState(void Function() updaterFunction) {
    void callSetState() {
      // Can only call setState if mounted
      if (mounted) {
        // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
        setState(updaterFunction);
      }
    }

    if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase ==
        SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks) {
      // Currently building, can't call setState --
      // need to add post-frame callback
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => callSetState());
    } else {
      callSetState();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using GetX and a Slider. To my slider, I used a the Rx variable directly instead of the actual value.

My Code previously.

```
RxDouble sliderValue = 1.0.obs;

MySlider(
   value: this.sliderValue
)
```

I changed my code to:

```
MySlider(
   value: this.sliderValue.value
)
```

Now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem is GetBuilder()

My Code previously.

```dart
UserDataUptade(Map<String,dynamic> newUserData){
  userData=newUserData;
  update();
}
```

I changed my code to:

```dart
UserDataUptade(Map<String,dynamic> newUserData){
  userData=newUserData;
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    update();
  });
}
```

and it's works