# Flutter: possible to detect when a drawer is open?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to detect when a Drawer is open so that we can run some routine to update its content?

A typical use case I have would be to display the number of followers, likers... and for this, I would need to poll the server to get this information, then to display it.

I tried to implement a NavigatorObserver to catch the moment when the Drawer is made visible/hidden but the NavigatorObserver does not detect anything about the Drawer.

Here is the code linked to the NavigatorObserver:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef void OnObservation(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute);
typedef void OnStartGesture();

class NavigationObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  OnObservation onPushed;
  OnObservation onPopped;
  OnObservation onRemoved;
  OnObservation onReplaced;
  OnStartGesture onStartGesture;

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    if (onPushed != null) {
      onPushed(route, previousRoute);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    if (onPopped != null) {
      onPopped(route, previousRoute);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    if (onRemoved != null)
      onRemoved(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({ Route<dynamic> oldRoute, Route<dynamic> newRoute }) {
    if (onReplaced != null)
      onReplaced(newRoute, oldRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didStartUserGesture() { 
    if (onStartGesture != null){
      onStartGesture();
    }
  }
}
```

and the initialization of this observer

```
void main(){
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final NavigationObserver _observer = new NavigationObserver()
                                              ..onPushed = (Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
                                                print('** pushed route: $route');
                                              }
                                              ..onPopped = (Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
                                                print('** poped route: $route');
                                              }
                                              ..onReplaced = (Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
                                                print('** replaced route: $route');
                                              }
                                              ..onStartGesture = () {
                                                print('** on start gesture');
                                              };

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new SplashScreen(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          '/splashscreen': (BuildContext context) => new SplashScreen(),
        },
        navigatorObservers: <NavigationObserver>[_observer],
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: NavigatorObserver is not the solution. Can you instead show how you use Drawer ?

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet.  There is nothing special on the way I use the Drawer, there is very little to say.  I simply initialize the drawer at the Scaffold level.  I am waiting for a solution to detect when the drawer is open to further elaborate.

But as you mentioned that the NavigatorObserver was not the solution, have you anything else in mind ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think one simple solution is to override the `leading` property of your `AppBar` so you can have access when the menu icon is pressed an run your API calls based on that.

Yet I may have misunderstood your question because with the use case you provided, you usually need to manage it in a way that you can *listen* to any change which will update the value automatically so I am not sure what are you trying to trigger when the drawer is open.

Anyway here is the example.

[image]

```
class DrawerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerExampleState createState() => new _DrawerExampleState();
}

class _DrawerExampleState extends State<DrawerExample> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _counter =0;
  _handleDrawer(){
      _key.currentState.openDrawer();

           setState(() {
          ///DO MY API CALLS
          _counter++;
        });

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Drawer Example"),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(
          Icons.menu
        ),onPressed:_handleDrawer,),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(_counter.toString(),style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So simple and elegant...  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aziza This doesn't cater for a drawer that is slid open?

Comment: Won't detect drawer open via user slide action.

Comment: How to detect drawer with slide gesture ?

Answer (score 43):

As https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/67249 is already merged and published with Flutter 2.0 here is proper way to detect drawer open/close:

```
Scaffold(
      onDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
        //todo what you need for left drawer
      },
      onEndDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
        //todo what you need for right drawer
      },
)
```

Comment: Now that this feature is built in, this post should be updated to correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

## This answer is old now. Please see @dees91's answer.

### Detecting & Running Functions When Drawer Is Opened / Closed

- Run `initState()` when open drawer by any action.
- Run `dispose()` when close drawer by any action.

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        print("open");
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        print("close");
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Drawer(
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text("test1"),
                    Text("test2"),
                    Text("test3"),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

#### State Management Considerations

If you are altering state with these functions to rebuild drawer items, you may encounter the error: `Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build`.

This can be handled by using the following two functions in **initState()** [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478165/8177355)

**Option 1**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
  // Add Your Code here.
});
```

**Option 2**

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // add your code here.
});
```

**Full Example of Option 1**

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        // Your Code Here
    });
}
```

Comment: why is this not accepted?  This accounts for both button presses and sliding the drawer open

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. It should've been accepted.

Comment: Even though this is a good fix, it's still a workaround. Check @dees91's answer for a proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66600590/3197387

Answer (score 20):

**Best solution**

`ScaffoldState` has a useful method `isDrawerOpen` which provides the status of open/close.

**Example:** Here on the back press, it first checks if the drawer is open, if yes then first it will close before exit.

```
/// create a key for the scaffold in order to access it later.
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
Widget build(context) {
   return WillPopScope(
  child: Scaffold(
    // assign key (important)
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    drawer: SideNavigation(),
  onWillPop: () async {
    // drawer is open then first close it
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      return false;
    }
    // we can now close the app.
    return true;
  });}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use **onDrawerChanged** for detecting if the drawer is opened or closed in the Scaffold widget.

**Property :**

{void Function(bool)? onDrawerChanged}
Type: void Function(bool)?
Optional callback that is called when the Scaffold.drawer is opened or closed.

**Example :**

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Scaffold(
  onDrawerChanged:(val){
    if(val){
      setState(() {
        //foo bar;
      });
    }else{
      setState(() {
        //foo bar;
      });
    }
},     
  drawer: Drawer(        
      child: Container(
      )
  ));
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no [readymade solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14510).

You can use the dirty hack for this: to observe the visible position of the Drawer.

For example, I used this approach to synchronise the animation of the icon on the button and the location of the Drawer box.

[image]

The code that solves this problem you can see below:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

    class DrawerListener extends StatefulWidget {
      final Widget child;
      final ValueChanged<FractionalOffset> onPositionChange;

      DrawerListener({
        @required this.child,
        this.onPositionChange,
      });

      @override
      _DrawerListenerState createState() => _DrawerListenerState();
    }

    class _DrawerListenerState extends State<DrawerListener> {
      GlobalKey _drawerKey = GlobalKey();
      int taskID;
      Offset currentOffset;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _postTask();
      }

      _postTask() {
        taskID = SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback((_) {
          if (widget.onPositionChange != null) {
            final RenderBox box = _drawerKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
            if (box != null) {
              Offset newOffset = box.globalToLocal(Offset.zero);
              if (newOffset != currentOffset) {
                currentOffset = newOffset;
                widget.onPositionChange(
                  FractionalOffset.fromOffsetAndRect(
                    currentOffset,
                    Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, box.size.width, box.size.height),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
          }

          _postTask();
        });
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(taskID);
        if (widget.onPositionChange != null) {
          widget.onPositionChange(FractionalOffset(1.0, 0));
        }
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          key: _drawerKey,
          child: widget.child,
        );
      }
    }
```

If you are only interested in the final events of opening or closing the box, it is enough to call the callbacks in `initState` and `dispose` functions.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for sharing! Very useful if you need to sync the animation of a button with the drawer movement!

Comment: There is a readymade solution with Flutter 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66600590/11120544

This answer is from this question itself

Answer (score 0):

there is isDrawerOpen property in ScaffoldState so you can check whenever you want to check.

create a global key ;

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

assign it to scaffold

```
Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: ..)
```

check where ever in the app

```
bool opened =scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time this question was being posted it was a bit trick to accomplish this. But from Flutter 2.0, it is pretty easy. Inside your Scaffold you can detect both the right drawer and the left drawer as follows.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      onDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
        *//Left drawer, Your code here,*
      },
      onEndDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
        *//Right drawer, Your code here,*
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scaffold.of(context) as below to detect the Drawer status :

**NOTE: you must put your code in the Builder widget to use the context which contains scaffold.**

```
Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.menu,
                    color: getColor(context, opacity.value),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (Scaffold.of(context).isDrawerOpen) {
                      Scaffold.of(context).closeDrawer();
                    } else {
                      Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```