# How to detect the outside of the drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-drawer

How to detect the outside in the image?

To open the drawer I already know its function, but to tap the right side of the drawer I don't know

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Removing the drawer normally works out of the box. Since we don't know what you actually coded, or how your code behaves, we cannot help you. Please provide a [mcve], the behavior you expect and the behavior you observe instead.

Comment: I apologize for the uncertainty of my question because I am a new user, I want when tapping the outside of the drawer a message appears, how do I do it?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258939/how-catch-the-opening-and-closing-of-the-drawer-in-flutter

Comment: okay i will try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global boolean *isSideBarOpen* and make it **true** when it opens (best in the onPress() event of the button that opens it).
And make sure to set it **false** again once it closes.

You can add a GestureDetector to the Scaffold like this:

```
body: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () {
      if (isSideBarOpen) {
        // sideBar.close();
      }
    }
```

This checks whether the *sideBar* is open or not and closes it – with the appropriate code – when you tap anywhere else on the screen.

Comment: The issue is solved, thank you 