# Exception has occurred. Bad state: Future already completed in flutter listview and Video player

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting a video url I have stored from my CloudFirestore DB and displaying network videos in a listView.buiilder().
[image]
when I set

```
autiInitialize = true
```

or try to initialize the video in any other way I get Error

```
Exception has occurred.
Bad state: Future already completed
```

and

```
I/flutter ( 6187): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6187): The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController: 
I/flutter ( 6187): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter ( 6187): This MaterialControls widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already
I/flutter ( 6187): in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build
I/flutter ( 6187): phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the
I/flutter ( 6187): framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be
I/flutter ( 6187): built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter ( 6187): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter ( 6187):   MaterialControls(state: _MaterialControlsState#47383)
```

part of my code

```
VideoPlayerController  retcontroller(String varainatVideo){
    if(playercontroller == null){
      playercontroller = VideoPlayerController.network(varainatVideo);
    }
    return playercontroller;
  }


   Chewie(
  retcontroller(${snapshotDocuments[index].data['videos']}),
 autoInitialize: true,
cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(),
showControls:false,
 ),
```

Comment: Please format your code before pasting. Also, you haven't really included enough code for us to see what's going on here.

Comment: Also, make sure you initialize the video controller first before using it.

Comment: I am getting same error. How did you fix it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to change the state during the UI build, be sure you're not using `setState(...)` in `ListView.builder(...)`

Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build) as an example.