# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build exception prevents me from executing callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to execute a callback function once a timer ends in a particular widget but I keep getting this exception:

> I/flutter (16413): Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

So I have this widget called `countdown`:

```dart
class Countdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onCountdownExpire;

  Countdown(this.onCountdownExpire);

  @override
  CountdownState createState() => CountdownState();
}

class CountdownState extends State<Countdown> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString()}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status){
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)
          widget.onCountdownExpire();
    });
    controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
  } 
   ...
   ...
   ... // omitted code
}
```

So once the animation is completed it will call the callback function:

```dart
class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  ... // omitted code  

  @override
  void initState() {
   ... // omitted code
  }

  void onCountdownExpire() {
    setState(() {
      _topContentImage =  AssetImage(questions[questionNum++].imagePath);
    });
  }
  ... // omitted code
}
```

I've tried to follow a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build) but it does not work and gives me the same exception:

```dart
  void onCountdownExpire() => 
    setState(() {
      _topContentImage =  AssetImage(questions[questionNum++].imagePath);
    });
```

I also tried this but to no avail:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) =>
        (status == AnimationStatus.completed) ?
          widget.onCountdownExpire():null
    );
    controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try including 'dart:async':

```
import 'dart:async';
```

then try wrapping your call of the `onCountdownExpire` function in a short-lived `Timer()`:

```
...
        Timer(
          Duration(milliseconds:50),
          () {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)
              widget.onCountdownExpire();
          },
        );
...
```

this will make the `setState()` happen outside the build phase of the last frame of your animation.

The error occurs most likely because the `Countdown()` is being redrawn as part of the redraw of the `QuizPage()` widget. Adding the `Timer()` will force the update to happen outside of the `build()` scope, in an async fashion, and will still achieve the same results without the error.

Comment: ok i tried that and got this exception instead `I/flutter (16413): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2`

Comment: did you do a full restart? or just a hot reload? because this change was in the initState() method, you would need a full restart. also, the truncated error messaged ('Another exception...') usually means that a previous exception was thrown prior to that one. it would be helpful to understand what that exception was in order to narrow down the problem.

Comment: ok I think I know why range error is being thrown, its because `questions` only has 2 elements and it is calling [2], which is wrong. And the reason this is happening is because when the animation starts, it is somehow "completed" as I inserted a debug print just before calling `windget.onCountdownExpire()` and it prints when the animation starts not when it is finished.

Comment: i did a full restart

Comment: ok the reason it was status completed at the start : `controller.reverse(from: 1.0);`. After i changed it to `controller.animateTo(1.0);` it was completed at the end of the animation.

Comment: I could also use `controller.dismissed` instead of `controller.completed` to solve the completed at the start issue