# Can we pass parameters to reference methods in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Guys I am trying to access a variable inside a method and I had to pass this variable to reference method. is that possible?

This is my list builder

```
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: tasks.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TaskTile(
          nameOfTheTask: tasks[index].nameOfTheTask,
          isChecked: tasks[index].taskStatus,
          onTaskCompleted: (checkBoxState) {        
            setState(() {
              tasks[index].updateTaskStatus();
            });
          }, 
        );
      },
    );
```

I want to replace the callback near onTaskCompleted to a reference method.

```
onTaskChangedReference(checkBoxState) {
     setState(() {
       tasks[index].taskStatus =
           !tasks[indexOfTheTaskTile].taskStatus;
     });
   }
```

but I need to use the index variable, is there any way I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about doing that is to create a method like this:

```dart
onTaskChangedReference(int index) {
  return (checkBoxState) {
     setState(() {
       tasks[index].taskStatus =
           !tasks[indexOfTheTaskTile].taskStatus;
     });
   }
}
```

So now in your `ListView.builder`, you can reference it like this:

```dart
...
onTaskCompleted: onTaskChangedReference(index),
...
```

Comment: I did as you said and then I got the error setState() or markNeedBuild() called during build. error

Comment: It might have something to do with the `TaskTile` implementation, check if you have something like this in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592505/1006555