# Flutter: SnackBar not displayed after calling setState() method

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-snackbar

I'm implementing this products app where a user can add a product from his wish list and add it to their cart. Once the user clicks the add to cart button, I want to delete the product from the screen and display a "success" `Snackbar`.
Since the products are loaded and displayed from FireBase Firestore, I delete the item and call `setState({});` so that the list on the screen will be updated. The problem is that the `SnackBar` that comes right after `setState({});` isn't shown.

I assume it is because the widget tree is rebuilt so the current state and context are "gone".
I tried finding some information online but haven't managed to find anything useful. I also tried to make a workaround with a `bool` flag that will be set once the user clicks the "Add to cart" button using and on `setState` the flag will be true one time to show the `SnackBar` when the widget tree is rebuilt and then turn the flag back to off but it didn't work as well.

What am I missing? How can I display a `SnackBar` after calling `setState({})`?

here is my code: (line in question marked with `FIXME:`)

[slidable package installation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable/install)

```dart
  final GlobalKey _repaintBoundaryKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKeyWishList = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final Center _circularProgressIndicator = Center(
    child: SizedBox(
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightGreen[800]),
        )
    ),
  );

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Wishlists").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> wishListSnapshot) {
          if (wishListSnapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return _circularProgressIndicator;
          } else if (!wishListSnapshot.hasData ||
              0 == wishListSnapshot.data.data()['Wishlist'].length) {
            return globals.emptyListErrorScreen(context, 'Wishlist');
          }
          int totalProducts = wishListSnapshot.data.data()['Wishlist'].length;
          return Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKeyWishList,
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[800],
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: totalProducts * 2,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int i) {
                            if (i >= 2 * totalProducts) {
                              return null;
                            }
                            if (i.isOdd) {
                              return Divider(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                thickness: 1.0,
                              );
                            }
                            var wishlistIdData = wishListSnapshot.data.data()['Wishlist'];
                            String productID = wishlistIdData[i ~/ 2];
                            return FutureBuilder(
                              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products").doc(productID).get(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> productSnapshot) {
                                if (wishListSnapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done || !productSnapshot.hasData) {
                                  return _circularProgressIndicator;
                                }
                                var productData = productSnapshot.data.data()['Product'];
                                String prodName = productData['name'];
                                String prodPrice = productData['price'];
                                String prodDate = productData['date'];
                                return Slidable(
                                  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                                  actionExtentRatio: 0.22,
                                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    //add to cart
                                    IconSlideAction(
                                      caption: 'Add to cart',
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      foregroundColor: Colors
                                          .amberAccent,
                                      icon: Icons.add_shopping_cart,
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        globals.userCart.add(
                                            globals.Product(
                                                productID,
                                                FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
                                                prodName,
                                                double.parse(prodPrice),
                                                prodDate,
                                                [],
                                                "",
                                                "")
                                        );

                                        ///removing product from wishlist
                                        List toRemove = [];
                                        toRemove.add(productID);
                                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection('Wishlists')
                                            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                                            .get()
                                            .then((value) async {
                                          List<dynamic> list = List
                                              .from(value
                                              .data()['Wishlist']);
                                          list
                                            ..removeWhere((e) =>
                                                toRemove.contains(e));
                                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                              .collection('Wishlists')
                                              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                                              .update(
                                              {'Wishlist': list});
                                        });
                                        setState(() {
                                          ///to update the list on screen
                                        });
                                        //FIXME: snackbar not displayed after setState!
                                        ///showing snackbar upon completion
                                        _scaffoldKeyWishList
                                            .currentState
                                            .showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(
                                                'Product Successfully Added to Cart!',
                                                style: GoogleFonts
                                                    .lato(
                                                    fontSize: 13.0,
                                                    color: Colors
                                                        .white
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              behavior: SnackBarBehavior
                                                  .floating,
                                              action: SnackBarAction(
                                                label: 'Checkout',
                                                textColor: Colors
                                                    .lime,
                                                onPressed: () =>
                                                    showDialog(
                                                      context: context,
                                                      builder: (
                                                          BuildContext context) {
                                                        return CustomDialogBox();
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text(prodName,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontSize: 18.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(prodPrice + "\$",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontSize: 13.5,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    visualDensity: VisualDensity
                                        .adaptivePlatformDensity,
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                ]
              )
            )
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In my case I was calling `setState` method before build method complete process of building widgets.*

You can face this `error` if you are showing `snack bar` or `alert` dialog before the completion of build `method` and in many other cases. so in such situation use below call back function.

```
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        // add your snackbar code here
      });
```

or You can also use SchedulerBinding which does the same.

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

  // add your code here of snackbar.

});
```

or you can try this too (I am not sure about this one)

```
if(mounted){
  //add your code here of snackbar
}
```

[CREDITS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478165/9577961)

Comment: I want to display a `SnackBar` and because of that - using your solution results in an error of `The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.`. I display a `SnackBar` just as marked in my code under `FIXME`.