# Create ListView with infinite scrolling by provider: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-change-notifier

I am trying to create ListView where items are built while the screen is being scrolled. I am trying to add content by using provider.

I get an error "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" when calling notifyListener() inside itemBuilder.

I know the reason is because notifyListener() is called during ListView is built.

My questions are:

- is there a workaround to call notifyListener() after or before build?
- if this is not even an appropriate approach, what is the best approach to add content to ListView for infinite scrolling by using Provider?

This is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build) because his ListView widget doesn't have to be built over and over again as scroll happens.

my_app.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'suggestions.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Suggestions(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: RandomWords(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatelessWidget {
  final _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  void _addSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<Suggestions>(context, listen: false).addSuggestions();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var suggestions = Provider.of<Suggestions>(context).getSuggestions;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Startup Name Generator'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(suggestions),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions(suggestions) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd) {
            return Divider(); /*2*/
          }

          final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
          if (index >= suggestions.length) {
            _addSuggestions(context);
          }
          return _buildRow(suggestions[index]);
        });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
        Icons.favorite_border,
        color: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

suggestions.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

class Suggestions extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  get getSuggestions {
    return _suggestions;
  }

  void addSuggestions() {
    _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build)

Comment: @ajay I don't think so.

Comment: I have the exact same problem: I'm trying to adapt the official [Flutter tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab) to use providers. I assume anyone who tries this will run into this same issue, and it's very confusing as a new Flutter user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove notifyListeners() from addSuggestions();

It is because ListView is being built every time scroll happens. You do not need to use notifyListeners to rebuild the widget inside [a widget that rebuilds by itself](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#:%7E:text=ListView%20is%20the%20most%20commonly,extent%20in%20the%20scroll%20direction.).

Comment: But how to solve this general problem: "what is the best approach to add content to `ListView` for infinite scrolling by using `Provider`"? I.e. suppose that the data used to build the `ListView` comes from a `Provider` that is `watch`ed by other parts of the app, so that not calling `notifyListeners` is not an option?