# (Getting the error while building) setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.The relevant error-causing widget was MaterialApp

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run the application but the `setState error` is showing at `MaterialApp` where I have not used `setState`. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build) solution but it didn't work for me. The Code is a part of the `main.dart` file, the application is getting started but when I'm trying to navigate to the other page it's showing me the error at `main.dart` i.e the `MaterialApp` Function.

```
>   return MaterialApp(                //error here
      title: 'KoylaMandi',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 34.0,
          ),
        ),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            color: kPrimaryFontColor,
          ),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: kPrimaryFontColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SplashScreen(),
        '/phonesignup':(context) => MyLoginPage(),
        '/recent': (context) => PlacedordersWidget(),
        // '/signInbyOtp': (context) => SignInbyOtp(),
        'otp': (context) => Otp(),
        '/signIn': (context) => SignIn(),
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
        '/search': (context) => Search(),
        '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
        '/resetPass': (context) => PasswordResetPage(),
        '/signUp': (context) => SignUp(),
        '/myCart': (context) => MyCartPage(),
        '/about': (context) => AboutPage(),
        '/contact': (context) => ContactPage(),
        '/orders': (context) => MyOrderPage(),
        '/adminsplashScreen': (context) => AdminSplashScreen(),
        '/adminsignIn': (context) => AdminSignIn(),
        '/adminhome': (context) => AdminHome(),
        '/adminprimaryAd': (context) => PrimaryAdPage(),
        '/adminsecondaryAd': (context) => SecondaryAdPage(),
        '/admincategory': (context) => CategoriesPage(),
        '/adminproducts': (context) => ProductPage(),
        '/adminorders': (context) => OrdersPage(),
        '/admininquiry': (context) => InquiryPage(),
        '/adminqueries': (context) => ProductQueries(),
        '/adminaddProduct': (context) => AddProduct(),
        '/adminaddProperty': (context) => AddProperty(),
      },
      
    );
====================================ERROR==========================================
The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.


   
This _ModalScope<dynamic> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _ModalScope<dynamic>-[LabeledGlobalKey<_ModalScopeState<dynamic>>#48aee]
    state: _ModalScopeState<dynamic>#e2ff2
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Builder
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:48
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4292
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4307
#2      State.setState
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1264
#3      _ModalScopeState._routeSetState
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:769
#4      ModalRoute.setState
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:895
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the code where have you called the **setState((){})** function.

But given the error I can tell you're trying to call **setState** in the **init** function.

You can easily eliminate this error by checking whether the widget is mounted or not.

```
if(!mounted) return;
setState(() {});
```

This will call **setState** if the widget tree is not mounted.

Comment: It worked Thank you So much!

Comment: Great could you please mark this as answered?

Comment: Yes Sure Thank You So much