# Automatically determine whether to wait for a frame to avoid "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build"?

Tags: flutter, dart

As we know, if we `setState` during a widget build, it will error:

```
flutter: [extra#0] bound_extra.0 => FlutterError.onError raw stackTrace=#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4424:11)
flutter: #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4439:6)
flutter: #2      ObserverElementMixin.invalidate (package:flutter_mobx/src/observer_widget_mixin.dart:71:24)
flutter: #3      ReactionImpl._run (package:mobx/src/core/reaction.dart:117:22)
flutter: #4      ReactiveContext._runReactionsInternal (package:mobx/src/core/context.dart:351:18)
flutter: #5      ReactiveContext.runReactions (package:mobx/src/core/context.dart:325:5)
flutter: #6      ReactiveContext.endBatch (package:mobx/src/core/context.dart:155:7)
flutter: #7      ActionController.endAction (package:mobx/src/core/action.dart:110:9)
flutter: #8      AsyncAction._run (package:mobx/src/api/async/async_action.dart:46:16)
...
```

And the simple solution is to use `addPostFrameCallback` and do `setState` there.

However, in my case, I hope there exists a `smartSetState` which does the following:

- Whenever possible, it calls `setState` directly. Thus, we do not have a one-frame latency.
- If not possible (i.e. direct `setState` will lead to the error above), it waits for a frame and `setState` then.

How can this be implemented? I have searched whether there exists some state variable indicating whether the widget tree is building, but no results. Thanks!

P.S. I know there are already questions like [setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build), but I hope the `smartSetState` can automatically determine whether to wait or not, instead of blindly wait for a frame.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such functionality available in flutter. There are state management packages like [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) which loads your screen only when required and when the data is available which you can use.

You can however use `Future.wait()` to wait for the UI to build and also provide additional conditions like `if(mounted)` before `setState` to reduce exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does not solve the question :/

Comment: That's because flutter currently has no functionality like that.