# Problem with saving the address - error "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." How to solve this error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a project with Flutter. I am getting this warning, "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." This is big problem for me. How can I fix this problem?

This is warning.

> ======== Exception caught by foundation library ==================================================== The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for
> LocationProvider: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>
> This _InheritedProviderScope<LocationProvider?> widget cannot be
> marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
> process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be
> built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently
> building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds
> parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will
> always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget
> during this build phase. The widget on which setState() or
> markNeedsBuild() was called was:
> _InheritedProviderScope<LocationProvider?>   value: Instance of 'LocationProvider'   listening to value The widget which was currently
> being built when the offending call was made was: Builder When the
> exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Element.markNeedsBuild. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4424:11)
> #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4439:6)
> #2      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.markNeedsNotifyDependents (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:570:5)
> #3      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:308:24)
> #4      LocationProvider.setAddAddressData (package:flutter_grocery/provider/location_provider.dart:350:5)
> #5      _AddNewAddressScreenState._initLoading (package:flutter_grocery/view/screens/address/add_new_address_screen.dart:48:61)
> #6      _AddNewAddressScreenState.initState (package:flutter_grocery/view/screens/address/add_new_address_screen.dart:88:5)
> #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4893:57)
> #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5) ...     Normal
> element mounting (151 frames)
> #159    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
> #160    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
> #161    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
> #162    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5845:32)
> #163    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6445:17)
> #164    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #165    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
> #166    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
> #167    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
> #168    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
> #169    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #170    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
> #171    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
> #172    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
> #173    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #174    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
> #175    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
> #176    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
> #177    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:111:11)
> #178    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #179    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
> #180    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #181    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
> #182    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
> #183    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
> #184    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
> #185    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #186    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
> #187    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #188    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
> #189    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #190    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
> #191    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
> #192    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
> #193    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
> #206    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
> #207    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
> #208    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31) (elided 3 frames from dart:async) The LocationProvider sending notification was: Instance of
> 'LocationProvider'

This is my code

```
import ...

class LocationProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  final LocationRepo locationRepo;

  LocationProvider({@required this.sharedPreferences, this.locationRepo});

  Position _position = Position(longitude: 0, latitude: 0, timestamp: DateTime.now(), accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, heading: 1, speed: 1, speedAccuracy: 1);
  Position _pickPosition = Position(longitude: 0, latitude: 0, timestamp: DateTime.now(), accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, heading: 1, speed: 1, speedAccuracy: 1);
  bool _loading = false;
  bool get loading => _loading;
  TextEditingController _locationController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController get locationController => _locationController;
  Position get position => _position;
  Position get pickPosition => _pickPosition;
  Placemark _address = Placemark();
  Placemark _pickAddress = Placemark();
  String _currentAddressText = '';
  String get currentAddressText => _currentAddressText;

  Placemark get address => _address;
  Placemark get pickAddress => _pickAddress;
  List<Marker> _markers = <Marker>[];

  List<Marker> get markers => _markers;

  bool _buttonDisabled = true;
  bool _changeAddress = true;
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  List<Prediction> _predictionList = [];
  bool _updateAddAddressData = true;

  bool get buttonDisabled => _buttonDisabled;
  GoogleMapController get mapController => _mapController;

  // for get current location
  void getCurrentLocation(BuildContext context, bool fromAddress, {GoogleMapController mapController}) async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    Position _myPosition;
    try {
      Position newLocalData = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      _myPosition = newLocalData;
    }catch(e) {
      _myPosition = Position(
        latitude: double.parse('0'),
        longitude: double.parse('0'),
        timestamp: DateTime.now(), accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, heading: 1, speed: 1, speedAccuracy: 1,
      );
    }
    if(fromAddress) {
      _position = _myPosition;
    }else {
      _pickPosition = _myPosition;
    }
    if (mapController != null) {
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(_myPosition.latitude, _myPosition.longitude), zoom: 17),
      ));
    }
    Placemark _myPlaceMark;
    try {
      if(!ResponsiveHelper.isWeb()) {
        List<Placemark> placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(_myPosition.latitude, _myPosition.longitude);
        _myPlaceMark = placeMarks.first;
      }else {
        String _address = await getAddressFromGeocode(LatLng(_myPosition.latitude, _myPosition.longitude), context);
        _myPlaceMark = Placemark(name: _address, locality: '', postalCode: '', country: '');
      }
    }catch (e) {
      String _address = await getAddressFromGeocode(LatLng(_myPosition.latitude, _myPosition.longitude), context);
      _myPlaceMark = Placemark(name: _address, locality: '', postalCode: '', country: '');
    }
    fromAddress ? _address = _myPlaceMark : _pickAddress = _myPlaceMark;
    if(fromAddress) {
      _locationController.text = placeMarkToAddress(_address);
    }
    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updatePosition(CameraPosition position, bool fromAddress, String address, BuildContext context, bool forceNotify) async {
    if(_updateAddAddressData || forceNotify) {
      _loading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      try {
        if (fromAddress) {
          _position = Position(
            latitude: position.target.latitude, longitude: position.target.longitude, timestamp: DateTime.now(),
            heading: 1, accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, speedAccuracy: 1, speed: 1,
          );
        } else {
          _pickPosition = Position(
            latitude: position.target.latitude, longitude: position.target.longitude, timestamp: DateTime.now(),
            heading: 1, accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, speedAccuracy: 1, speed: 1,
          );
        }
        if (_changeAddress) {
          if (!ResponsiveHelper.isWeb()) {
            List<Placemark> placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.target.latitude, position.target.longitude);
            fromAddress ? _address = placeMarks.first : _pickAddress = placeMarks.first;
          } else {
            String _addresss = await getAddressFromGeocode(LatLng(position.target.latitude, position.target.longitude), context);
            fromAddress ? _address = Placemark(name: _addresss) : _pickAddress = Placemark(name: _addresss);
          }
          if(address != null) {
            _locationController.text = address;
          }else if(fromAddress) {
            _locationController.text = placeMarkToAddress(_address);
          }
        } else {
          _changeAddress = true;
        }
      } catch (e) {}
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }else {
      _updateAddAddressData = true;
    }
  }

  // End Address Position
  void draggableAddress() async {
    try {
      _loading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      if(ResponsiveHelper.isMobilePhone()) {
        List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(_position.latitude, _position.longitude);
        _address = placemarks.first;
        _locationController.text = placeMarkToAddress(_address);
      }
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }catch(e) {
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  // delete user address
  void deleteUserAddressByID(int id, int index, Function callback) async {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = await locationRepo.removeAddressByID(id);
    if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
      _addressList.removeAt(index);
      callback(true, 'Deleted address successfully');
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      String errorMessage;
      if (apiResponse.error is String) {
        print(apiResponse.error.toString());
        errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
      } else {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = apiResponse.error;
        print(errorResponse.errors[0].message);
        errorMessage = errorResponse.errors[0].message;
      }
      callback(false, errorMessage);
    }
  }

  bool _isAvaibleLocation = false;

  bool get isAvaibleLocation => _isAvaibleLocation;

  // user address
  List<AddressModel> _addressList;

  List<AddressModel> get addressList => _addressList;

  Future<ResponseModel> initAddressList(BuildContext context) async {
    ResponseModel _responseModel;
    ApiResponse apiResponse = await locationRepo.getAllAddress();
    if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
      _addressList = [];
      apiResponse.response.data.forEach((address) => _addressList.add(AddressModel.fromJson(address)));
      _responseModel = ResponseModel(true, 'successful');
    } else {
      ApiChecker.checkApi(context, apiResponse);
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return _responseModel;
  }

  bool _isLoading = false;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  String _errorMessage = '';
  String get errorMessage => _errorMessage;
  String _addressStatusMessage = '';
  String get addressStatusMessage => _addressStatusMessage;
  updateAddressStatusMessage({String message}){
    _addressStatusMessage = message;
  }
  updateErrorMessage({String message}){
    _errorMessage = message;
  }

  Future<ResponseModel> addAddress(AddressModel addressModel, BuildContext context) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _errorMessage = '';
    _addressStatusMessage = null;
    ApiResponse apiResponse = await locationRepo.addAddress(addressModel);
    _isLoading = false;
    ResponseModel responseModel;
    if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map map = apiResponse.response.data;
      initAddressList(context);
      String message = map["message"];
      responseModel = ResponseModel(true, message);
      _addressStatusMessage = message;
    } else {
      String errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
      if (apiResponse.error is String) {
        print(apiResponse.error.toString());
        errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
      } else {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = apiResponse.error;
        print(errorResponse.errors[0].message);
        errorMessage = errorResponse.errors[0].message;
      }
      responseModel = ResponseModel(false, errorMessage);
      _errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return responseModel;
  }

  // for address update screen
  Future<ResponseModel> updateAddress(BuildContext context, {AddressModel addressModel, int addressId}) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _errorMessage = '';
    _addressStatusMessage = null;
    ApiResponse apiResponse = await locationRepo.updateAddress(addressModel, addressId);
    _isLoading = false;
    ResponseModel responseModel;
    if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map map = apiResponse.response.data;
      initAddressList(context);
      String message = map["message"];
      responseModel = ResponseModel(true, message);
      _addressStatusMessage = message;
    } else {
      String errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
      if (apiResponse.error is String) {
        print(apiResponse.error.toString());
        errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
      } else {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = apiResponse.error;
        print(errorResponse.errors[0].message);
        errorMessage = errorResponse.errors[0].message;
      }
      responseModel = ResponseModel(false, errorMessage);
      _errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return responseModel;
  }

  // for save user address Section
  Future<void> saveUserAddress({Placemark address}) async {
    String userAddress = jsonEncode(address);
    try {
      await sharedPreferences.setString(AppConstants.USER_ADDRESS, userAddress);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  String getUserAddress() {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.USER_ADDRESS) ?? "";
  }

  // for Label Us
  List<String> _getAllAddressType = [];

  List<String> get getAllAddressType => _getAllAddressType;
  int _selectAddressIndex = 0;

  int get selectAddressIndex => _selectAddressIndex;

  updateAddressIndex(int index, bool notify) {
    _selectAddressIndex = index;
    if(notify) {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  initializeAllAddressType({BuildContext context}) {
    if (_getAllAddressType.length == 0) {
      _getAllAddressType = [];
      _getAllAddressType = locationRepo.getAllAddressType(context: context);
    }
  }

  void setLocation(String placeID, String address, GoogleMapController mapController) async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    PlacesDetailsResponse detail;
    ApiResponse response = await locationRepo.getPlaceDetails(placeID);
    detail = PlacesDetailsResponse.fromJson(response.response.data);

    _pickPosition = Position(
      longitude: detail.result.geometry.location.lat, latitude: detail.result.geometry.location.lng,
      timestamp: DateTime.now(), accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, heading: 1, speed: 1, speedAccuracy: 1,
    );

    _pickAddress = Placemark(name: address);
    _changeAddress = false;

    if(mapController != null) {
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(
        detail.result.geometry.location.lat, detail.result.geometry.location.lng,
      ), zoom: 17)));
    }
    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void disableButton() {
    _buttonDisabled = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setAddAddressData() {
    _position = _pickPosition;
    _address = _pickAddress;
    _locationController.text = placeMarkToAddress(_address);
    _updateAddAddressData = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void initialAddressData(BuildContext context) {
    _position = Position(longitude: double.parse(Provider.of<SplashProvider>(context, listen: false).configModel.ecommerceLocationCoverage.longitude ?? '0'),
        latitude: double.parse(Provider.of<SplashProvider>(context, listen: false).configModel.ecommerceLocationCoverage.latitude ?? '0'),timestamp: DateTime.now(),
        heading: 1, accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, speedAccuracy: 1, speed: 1);
    _address = _pickAddress;
    _locationController.text = placeMarkToAddress(_address);
    _updateAddAddressData = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setPickData() {
    _pickPosition = _position;
    _pickAddress = _address;
    _locationController.text = placeMarkToAddress(_address);
  }

  void setMapController(GoogleMapController mapController) {
    _mapController = mapController;
  }

  Future<String> getAddressFromGeocode(LatLng latLng, BuildContext context) async {
    ApiResponse response = await locationRepo.getAddressFromGeocode(latLng);
    String _address = 'Unknown Location Found';
    if(response.response.statusCode == 200 && response.response.data['status'] == 'OK') {
      _address = response.response.data['results'][0]['formatted_address'].toString();
    }else {
      ApiChecker.checkApi(context, response);
    }
    return _address;
  }

  Future<List<Prediction>> searchLocation(BuildContext context, String text) async {
    if(text != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      ApiResponse response = await locationRepo.searchLocation(text);
      if (response.response.statusCode == 200 && response.response.data['status'] == 'OK') {
        _predictionList = [];
        response.response.data['predictions'].forEach((prediction) => _predictionList.add(Prediction.fromJson(prediction)));
      } else {
        ApiChecker.checkApi(context, response);
      }
    }
    return _predictionList;
  }

  String placeMarkToAddress(Placemark placeMark) {
    return '${placeMark.name ?? ''}'
        ' ${placeMark.subAdministrativeArea ?? ''}'
        ' ${placeMark.isoCountryCode ?? ''}';
  }

}
```

My UI
`My UI code

```
class AddressScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final AddressModel addressModel;
  AddressScreen({this.addressModel});

  @override
  State<AddressScreen> createState() => _AddressScreenState();
}

class _AddressScreenState extends State<AddressScreen> {
  bool _isLoggedIn;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _isLoggedIn = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).isLoggedIn();
    if(_isLoggedIn) {
      Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).initAddressList(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: ResponsiveHelper.isMobilePhone()? null: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)? PreferredSize(child: WebAppBar(), preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120)) : AppBarBase(),
        body: _isLoggedIn ? Consumer<LocationProvider>(
          builder: (context, locationProvider, child) {
            return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                await Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).initAddressList(context);
              },
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 560 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                  child: Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 1170,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? 20 : 0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [

                              Text(
                                getTranslated('saved_address', context),
                                style: poppinsRegular.copyWith(color: ColorResources.getTextColor(context)),
                              ),
                              InkWell(
                               // onTap:() =>  Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteHelper.getAddAddressRoute('address', 'add', AddressModel())),
                                 onTap:() {Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).updateAddressStatusMessage(message: '');
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteHelper.getAddAddressRoute('address', 'add', AddressModel()), arguments: AddNewAddressScreen());
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 5),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Colors.transparent,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),

                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.add, color: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)? Colors.white : ColorResources.getTextColor(context)),
                                      Text(
                                        getTranslated('add_new', context),
                                        style: poppinsRegular.copyWith(color: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)? Colors.white : ColorResources.getTextColor(context)),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      locationProvider.addressList != null ? locationProvider.addressList.length > 0 ?

                      Scrollbar(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 1170,
                                child: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                                    ?  GridView.builder(
                                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisSpacing: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? 13 : 5,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? 13 : 5,
                                      childAspectRatio:ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? 4.5 : ResponsiveHelper.isTab(context) ? 4 : 3.5,
                                      crossAxisCount: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? 2 : ResponsiveHelper.isTab(context) ? 2 : 1),
                                  itemCount: locationProvider.addressList.length,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_DEFAULT,vertical: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_DEFAULT),
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return AddressWidget(
                                      addressModel: locationProvider.addressList[index],
                                      index: index,
                                    );
                                  },
                                )
                                    : ListView.builder(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                                  itemCount: locationProvider.addressList.length,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => AddressWidget(
                                    addressModel: locationProvider.addressList[index],
                                    index: index,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            locationProvider.addressList.length <= 4 ?  const SizedBox(height: 300) : SizedBox(),
                            ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? FooterView() : SizedBox(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                          : NoDataScreen()
                          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ) : NotLoggedInScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: take a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build

Comment: @MohamadBastin I don't understand what I should do after looking at that topic. If you know the solution, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a future (`initAddressList`) in `initState`, which calls `notifyListeners`, resulting in a rebuild. Since `initState` is not async, this means that the future will likely be completed during the framework is already in the process of building your widget. This is what the error message is about.

Although you can work this around using `addPostFramCallBack`, a better solution is to move this logic from `initState` into the `build` method, using a `FutureBuilder`, [see here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). This way the widget build will only start after your future is completed, and you can display a progress indicator while waiting for the future to be completed.