# Flutter Argument passing

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to pass argument to a button widget but I'm getting below error message.

Here is my argument:

```
ElevatedRegisterButton(
                navigator: Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return const RegisterPage1();
            })))
```

Here is my widget where I was trying to pass argument:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ElevatedRegisterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElevatedRegisterButton({super.key, required this.navigator});

  final String navigator;

  @override
  State<ElevatedRegisterButton> createState() => _ElevatedRegisterButtonState();
}

class _ElevatedRegisterButtonState extends State<ElevatedRegisterButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.navigator;
      },
      child: const Text('Register'),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: Looks like a type issue. The `navigator` specified by you accepts a `String` type value whereas the value passed if of type `Future`.  Maybe changing the type accepted or updating the passed value will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `navigator` member to type `final void Function()`, because the `onPressed` property of `ElevatedButton` requires this type. You also need to pass it differently, because `push` is another type of function. Lastly, simply set `onPressed` to `widget.navigator`.

An example code is below based on your code snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      const MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SafeArea(
        // see the difference, push is within () {}
        child: ElevatedRegisterButton(navigator: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RegisterPage1()));
        }),
      );
}

class ElevatedRegisterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElevatedRegisterButton({super.key, required this.navigator});

  final void Function() navigator;

  @override
  State<ElevatedRegisterButton> createState() => _ElevatedRegisterButtonState();
}

class _ElevatedRegisterButtonState extends State<ElevatedRegisterButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
        // here simply set the function
        onPressed: widget.navigator,
        child: const Text('Register'),
      );
}

// added for demo purposes
class RegisterPage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterPage1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      const Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: Text('RegisterPage1')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

In your code:

```dart
class ElevatedRegisterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElevatedRegisterButton({super.key, required this.navigator});

  // this line
  final String navigator;
```

you are accepting a `String navigator`; but you are passing to it a `Future`:

```dart
ElevatedRegisterButton(
                navigator: Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return const RegisterPage1();
            })))
```

**problem 2**

If you try running your code, you'll get an error:

```dart
setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build
```

So, to fix the issues, refactor your code as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: ElevatedRegisterButton(navigator: Navigator.of(context))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ElevatedRegisterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElevatedRegisterButton({super.key, required this.navigator});

  final NavigatorState navigator;
  @override
  State<ElevatedRegisterButton> createState() => _ElevatedRegisterButtonState();
}

class _ElevatedRegisterButtonState extends State<ElevatedRegisterButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      onPressed: () {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          widget.navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Text("h1"),
          ));
        });
      },
      child: const Text('Register'),
    );
  }
}
```

##### See also

[setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build)