# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build and how to fix Flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate

I am displaying a popup survey in my app so after completing the survey and clicking done, the popup appears again. I do not want that to open.

I get this error
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build which makes the widget show time and time again without completing.

I tried different solution but I cannot just get to the solution.
Can I please get assistance where I am getting it wrong.

My code of my method:

```
  void showGenexPopup() {
    final GenexViewModel genexViewModel =
        Provider.of<GenexViewModel>(context, listen: false);

    if (!genexViewModel.videoTrigger) {
      genexViewModel.showSurvey(
        context: context,
        pageId: GenexPageId.SearchPage,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      );
    }
  }
```

Where I am calling the method:

```
  Widget buildSearchResults(GlobalSearchViewModel globalSearchViewModel) {
    if (globalSearchViewModel.loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.busy) {
      return getLoader();
    } else {
      switch (categorizedResults.length) {
        case 0:
          {
            return buildNoDataFound();
          }
        case 1:
          {
            return buildList(categorizedResults[0].categorizedResults);
          }
        default:
          {
            for (final CategorizedResults list in categorizedResults) {
              if (list.categorizedResults.isNotEmpty) {
                dynamicTabHeaders.add(list.categoryTitle);
                if (list.categoryTitle == 'News' ||
                    list.categoryTitle == 'Videos') {
                  dynamicContent.add(
                    Scaffold(
                      body: ArticleVideoListViewWidget(list.categorizedResults),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (list.categoryTitle == 'Teams') {
                  for (final CategorizedTeams team in categorizedTeams) {
                    if (team.categorizedTeams.isNotEmpty) {
                      dynamicTeamTabHeaders.add(team.categoryTitle);
                      dynamicTeamContent.add(
                        Scaffold(
                          body: PlainListViewWidget(
                              searchValues: team.categorizedTeams),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                  dynamicContent.add(
                    Scaffold(
                      body: PillTabBar(
                        tabHeadings: dynamicTeamTabHeaders,
                        tabBodies: dynamicTeamContent,
                        initialIndex: 0,
                        scrollViewScroll: false,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  dynamicContent.add(
                    Scaffold(
                      body: PlainListViewWidget(
                          searchValues: list.categorizedResults),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
            }

            showGenexPopup();
            return sliverController.singleRowSearchTabSliverWithoutHeader(
              dynamicTabHeaders,
              dynamicContent,
              0,
              screenWidth(context),
              dynamicTabHeaders.length > 3,
              tabCallBack: this,
            );
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592301/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Elmarakby I tried that solution, does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to `setState` or anything that sets this widget as dirty see the widget lifecycle for a better understanding before the build function finishes.

on your situation you are trying to show a dialog that as you can see from the Error it marks this widget as need build

consider using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to show the dialog after the first frame has been called.

Solution

```
 void showGenexPopup() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

   final GenexViewModel genexViewModel =
       Provider.of<GenexViewModel>(context, listen: false);

   if (!genexViewModel.videoTrigger) {
     genexViewModel.showSurvey(
       context: context,
       pageId: GenexPageId.SearchPage,
       duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
     );
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi @AbdelrahmanM thanks, but the problem still proceeds.

Comment: what happens ??

Comment: The popup still appears again and the same error still shows

Comment: try calling it in `initState` when `categorizedResults.length` is not 0 or 1  it will work

Comment: how using my code

Comment: remove `showGenexPopup` from build and call it in `initState()`