# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a function in my Flutter app that displays data on the home screen. However, I'm encountering an issue where every time a user navigates to the home screen or moves to another screen, I get a "setState" error. Additionally, there's a noticeable glitch or black screen that appears at the end of the home screen transition.

Code:

```
   void showData() async {
    final homeLoadingProvider =
        Provider.of<HomeLoadingProvider>(context, listen: false);
    homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(true); // Set loading to true initially

    final processedLists = Set<String>();
    // Check if there is any data in the 'GroceryLists' node initially
    await databaseReference.child('GroceryLists').get().then((snapshot) async {
      if (snapshot.value == null) {
        homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(false);
        return; // Return early if there's no data
      }
    });
    // Get the current user
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    //print('user : ${user}');

    // Check if the user is logged in and get their UID
    if (user != null) {
      String currentUid = user.uid;
      //print('currentUid : ${currentUid}');
      databaseReference
          .child('GroceryLists')
          .onChildAdded
          .listen((event) async {
        try {
          var groceryListKey = event.snapshot.key;
          var value = event.snapshot.value;

          if (value is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
            Map<String, dynamic> groceryListValue =
                Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
            String? listName = groceryListValue['listName'] as String?;
            String? listId = groceryListValue['id'] as String?;
            String? userId =
                groceryListValue['Members'][currentUid]['userId'] as String?;
            // print('userId inside Members node : ${userId}');

            if (listName != null &&
                listId != null &&
                userId == currentUid && // Check if userId matches currentUid
                !processedLists.contains(listName)) {
              processedLists.add(listName);
              var itemValueMap = await fetchItemsForList(groceryListKey!);
              //print('itemValueMap : ${itemValueMap}');
              var colorID = groceryListValue['colorID'] ?? "";

              List<String> simpleItems = [];
              List<bool> isCheckedItems = [];

              if (itemValueMap.isNotEmpty) {
                itemValueMap.forEach((key, itemValue) {
                  if (itemValue is Map<dynamic, dynamic> &&
                      itemValue['category'] is Map) {
                    var categoryItems = itemValue['category']['item'] as List?;
                    var categoryName =
                        itemValue['category']['categoryName'] as String?;

                    if (categoryItems != null && categoryName != "Done") {
                      for (var item in categoryItems) {
                        if (item is Map) {
                          String? itemName = item['itemName'] as String?;

                          if (itemName != null) {
                            simpleItems.add(itemName);

                            // Check if the item is marked as done in "Done" category
                            var doneCategory = itemValueMap.entries.firstWhere(
                                (entry) => (entry.value['category']
                                        ['categoryName'] ==
                                    "Done"),
                                orElse: () => MapEntry(
                                    null, {}) // returning dummy MapEntry here
                                );

                            bool isDone = false;
                            if (doneCategory.key != null) {
                              var doneItems = doneCategory.value['category']
                                  ['item'] as List?;
                              var doneItem = doneItems?.firstWhere(
                                  (doneItem) =>
                                      doneItem['itemName'] == itemName,
                                  orElse: () => null);
                              isDone = doneItem != null &&
                                  doneItem['isDone'] == true;
                            }

                            isCheckedItems.add(isDone);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                });
                String? createdAtString =
                    groceryListValue['createdAt'] as String?;
                DateTime? createdAt = createdAtString != null
                    ? DateTime.parse(createdAtString)
                    : DateTime.now();
                if (simpleItems.length == isCheckedItems.length) {
                  groceryLists.add(GroceryList(
                    listName: listName,
                    items: simpleItems,
                    colorID: colorID,
                    id: listId,
                    isChecked: isCheckedItems,
                    createdAt: createdAt, // Add this line
                  ));
                  groceryLists.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.compareTo(
                      a.createdAt)); // sorting in descending order of createdAt
                  setState(() {});
                }
              }
            }
          }
          // Set isLoading to false when the processing for this child is done.
          homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(false);
        } catch (e) {
          print("Error while processing grocery list data: $e");
          homeLoadingProvider.setLoading(false);
        }
      });
    } else {
      print('user has not logged in till now');
    }
  }

  Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> fetchItemsForList(String groceryListKey) async {
    var itemsSnapshot = await databaseReference
        .child('GroceryLists/$groceryListKey/items')
        .get();
    if (itemsSnapshot.value is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
      return itemsSnapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
    }
    return {};
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478165/9409460